# Pivot Table: Sort row by hidden field

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, sorting, tree-view

I have a table in Excel 2016 (source: Microsoft Query/ODBC):

[image]

Raw data:

```
Construction Type   Location                          Sort
Reconstruction      Main St - Red St to Blue St       1
Reconstruction      Main St - Blue St to Green St     2
Reconstruction      Main St - Green St to Orange St   3
Restoration         Side St - Purple St to Yellow St  1
Restoration         Side St - Yellow St to Orange St  2
Restoration         Side St - Orange St to Grey St    3
```

I can create a pivot table like so:

[image]

I want to sort the Location field using the `Sort` column from the raw data (ascending).

- I don't want to manually move the rows.
- I don't want to include the Sort numbers as a prefix to the Location field. I want the Sort numbers to be hidden.

---

Is there a way to sort the rows via a hidden column?

Comment: This is possible in Power Pivot. Do you have the Power Pivot add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Sort column as a field under Sum of Values.
2. **NB!** click/select any *location* field in the pivot table (e.g. any "Main St...")
3. Without changing the selection above, click the dropdown arrow next to "Row Labels", then select "More sort options"
4. Select "Ascending (A to Z) by:", and "Sum of Sort" in the dropdown

[image]

5. Hide the "Sum of Sort" column in Excel.
6. Don't touch the "Row Labels" dropdown again (if you want, hide it via the ribbon "PivotTable Analyze > Show > Field Headers").

[image]

Bonus: refreshing the pivot table still maintains the sort.

Ps. Also hide +/- buttons via the ribbon "PivotTable Analyze > Show > +/- Buttons". And hide the grand total via the ribbon "PivotTable Analyze > PivotTable > Options > Totals & Filters >" deselect both "Show grand totals...".